# How to remove SharedPreferences from Array

Tags: android

I have problem with removing items from ArrayList. I tried it maybe 100 times but I can't fix it. Saving to list isn't problem but it's very hard to remove for me.

When I remove SharedPrefs key (position) It's good first time but if I first time remove first position it's deleted from list but its still in preferences so when I try to remove first position second time I cant remove it because there is still saved preference with value "" but I need to remove this preference totally that first position have to contain preferences with value on second position not "".

I tried to make some images for better understanding.
Thats before remove 1st position:
[image: image1]

And this is after remove 1st position

[image: image2]

There is my CustomListAdapter class

```
public class CustomListAdapterInterests extends ArrayAdapter < String > {

    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList < String > mItemInterest;

    public CustomListAdapterInterests(Activity context, ArrayList < String > itemInterest) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_interests, itemInterest);

        this.context = context;
        this.mItemInterest = itemInterest;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mItemInterest.size();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_interests, null, true);

        TextView itemInterestTV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textInterest);

        itemInterestTV.setText(mItemInterest.get(position));
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

And here is my fragment

```
public class InterestsFragment extends BaseFragment {

    private ArrayList < String > mInterestList;
    private static final int MAX_STORED_LINES_INTERESTS = 50;
    private FloatingActionButton plusInterestsBTN;
    private CustomListAdapterInterests adapterInterests;
    private ListView listInterests;
    private EditText interestET;
    private Button confirmInterestBTN;
    public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_interests, container, false);

        plusInterestsBTN = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.plusInterests);
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREFERENCES_INTERESTS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mInterestList = new ArrayList < String > ();
        loadInterestFromPreferences(mInterestList);
        adapterInterests = new CustomListAdapterInterests(getActivity(), mInterestList);

        listInterests = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewInterests);
        listInterests.setAdapter(adapterInterests);

        listInterests.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {


                if (sharedPreferences.contains(Constants.INTEREST + position)) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    mInterestList.remove(position);
                    adapterInterests.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    editor.remove(Constants.INTEREST + position);



                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });

        listInterests.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {@Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView <? > arg0, View arg1,
            final int position, long id) {
                onShowDialogSetItem(position);
                return true;
            }
        });

        plusInterestsBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onShowDialogAddItem();
            }

        });

        listInterests.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {@Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                int btn_initPosY = plusInterestsBTN.getScrollY();

                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    plusInterestsBTN.animate().cancel();
                    plusInterestsBTN.animate().translationXBy(350);
                } else {
                    plusInterestsBTN.animate().cancel();
                    plusInterestsBTN.animate().translationX(btn_initPosY);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    private void loadInterestFromPreferences(ArrayList < String > mInterestList) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {

            String interests = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.INTEREST + x, Constants.DEFAULT);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), interests, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (interests != "") {
                mInterestList.add(interests);
            }


        }
    }


    private void onShowDialogSetItem(final int position) {
        final Dialog dialogInterest = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialogInterest.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.anim.abc_slide_in_top;
        dialogInterest.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogInterest.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.animationName;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_interests_add_event, null, false);

        dialogInterest.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialogInterest.setContentView(view);

        final EditText interestET = (EditText) dialogInterest.findViewById(R.id.editTextInterest);
        Button confirmInterestBTN = (Button) dialogInterest.findViewById(R.id.confirmInterest);
        TextView title = (TextView) dialogInterest.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        title.setText("Edit Interest");
        interestET.setText(mInterestList.get(position));

        confirmInterestBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("2", "" + position);
                String interest = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.INTEREST + position, Constants.DEFAULT);



                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(Constants.INTEREST + position, interestET.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
                String interests = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.INTEREST + position, Constants.DEFAULT);

                mInterestList.set(position, interestET.getText().toString());


                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Upravené: " + interests, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                adapterInterests.notifyDataSetChanged();
                dialogInterest.dismiss();

            }
        });
        dialogInterest.show();
    }
    private void onShowDialogAddItem() {

        if (mInterestList.size() >= MAX_STORED_LINES_INTERESTS) {
            return;
        }
        final Dialog dialogInterest = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialogInterest.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.anim.abc_slide_in_top;
        dialogInterest.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogInterest.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.animationName;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_interests_add_event, null, false);

        dialogInterest.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialogInterest.setContentView(view);

        interestET = (EditText) dialogInterest.findViewById(R.id.editTextInterest);
        confirmInterestBTN = (Button) dialogInterest.findViewById(R.id.confirmInterest);

        confirmInterestBTN.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = listInterests.getAdapter().getCount();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(Constants.INTEREST + position, interestET.getText().toString());
                editor.commit();
                String interests = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.INTEREST + position, Constants.DEFAULT);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Přidané: " + interests, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mInterestList.add(interestET.getText().toString());
                //adapterInterests.notifyDataSetChanged();

                dialogInterest.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialogInterest.show();
        adapterInterests.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Thank you for help. Sorry for my English. If do you will help me I can do any material design app icon for you or google play designs. Thank you. If there is few informations please say me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you save all of your string list to single property of preferences will make it easy to manage.

see this sample:

```
//for save
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String interest : mInterestList) {
    sb.append(interest).append(",");
}
prefsEditor.putString("MyInterests", sb.toString());
prefsEditor.commit();

//for read
String [] interests= sharedPreferences.getString("MyInterests");
mInterestList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(interests));
```

in every change to your `mInterestList` just save it again. no need to remove and adding. change your `mInterestList` and save again in shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your adapter runs off of mInterestList .
I don't see you removing the data item from mInterestsList when your remove the Preference?

Comment: Hello I now edited my code (below remove prefs) 
I added 
`mInterestList.remove(position);
adapterInterests.notifyDataSetChanged();`
But it doesn't change anything
Thank you for answer :).

Comment: You have already built the adapter. Try calling adapterInterests.remove()

Comment: I tried it but again it doesn't work. I think it remove great from list but I think there is problem with preferences.. or I don't know I need help

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking whether shared preferences contains, see if it is set to null instead or not, that is do,

```
 if (sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.INTEREST + position)!=null) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                mInterestList.remove(position);
                adapterInterests.notifyDataSetChanged();
                editor.remove(Constants.INTEREST + position);



                editor.commit();
            }
```