# How to save bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I usually don't work with images. I tried it. App will onBttnClick show gallery and user can choose picture and he has to crop it. It will save great but I want to save it and use cropped image until user change it.

So please can you tell me how can I save image for later use ?

Here is code in Activity

```
public void onImage(View view){
    //Přechod do třídy GalleryUtil
    Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GalleryUtil.class);
    startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
}

//Vyhodnocení zadaných údajů
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String picturePath = data.getStringExtra("picturePath");
            performCrop(picturePath);
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == RESULT_CROP ) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(getCroppedBitmap(selectedBitmap));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/images"; // save to SD Card in images folder. Make sure path is there !
            OutputStream fOut = null;

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
            String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
            File file = new File(path, "Cropped_Image_"+currentDateandTime+".jpg"); // the File to save to
            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Bitmap pictureBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(selectedBitmap); // Using the cropped bitmap.
            pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
            try {
                fOut.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}

private void performCrop(String picUri) {
    try {


        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        File f = new File(picUri);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

        cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        // indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 280);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 280);

        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // display an error message
        String errorMessage = "your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}

public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);


    return output;
}
```

}

And here is my GalleryUtil code

```
public class GalleryUtil extends Activity{

private final static int RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE = 100;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final String TAG = "GalleryUtil";

String mCurrentPhotoPath;
File photoFile = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try{
        //Pick Image From Gallery
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(requestCode){
        case RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE:

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                try{
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);


                    //return Image Path to the Main Activity
                    Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                    returnFromGalleryIntent.putExtra("picturePath",picturePath);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,returnFromGalleryIntent);
                    finish();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
                    finish();
                }
            }else{
                Log.i(TAG,"RESULT_CANCELED");
                Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
                finish();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Error:

> 12-04 23:00:25.521 1728-1728/com.tomiktuts.tom.mygirlfriendapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.tomiktuts.tom.mygirlfriendapp, PID: 1728
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=400, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.tomiktuts.tom.mygirlfriendapp/com.tomiktuts.tom.mygirlfriendapp.DashBoardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4067)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4110)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
>                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                        at android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.java:1143)
>                                                                                        at com.tomiktuts.tom.mygirlfriendapp.DashBoardActivity.onActivityResult(DashBoardActivity.java:161)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6549)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4063)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4110) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:177) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)

Thank you for help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `Bitmap.compress()` method to save a Bitmap as a file. It will compress your picture and push it into an OutputStream.

I think the best thing would be to add below logic just when imageview is set using `getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)` (which is called after `performCrop(String picUri)` is performed).

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

OutputStream fOut = null;

// Lets save using date
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
String fileName = "Cropped_Image_" + currentDateandTime + ".png";

// Not sure if the / is on the path or not
File file = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName); // the File to save to
fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

Bitmap pictureBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(selectedBitmap); // Using the cropped bitmap.
pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
fOut.flush();
fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream

MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
```

Hope this helps !

Remember to add below to manifest, if you have not :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Complete Working Code** :

GalleryUtil.java

```
    package com.example.user.myapplication;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;

    import java.io.File;

    public class GalleryUtil extends Activity {

        private final static int RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE = 100;
        public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
        private static final String TAG = "GalleryUtil";

        String mCurrentPhotoPath;
        File photoFile = null;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            try{
                //Pick Image From Gallery
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            switch(requestCode){
                case RESULT_SELECT_IMAGE:

                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                        try{
                            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                            cursor.moveToFirst();
                            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);


                            //return Image Path to the Main Activity
                            Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                            returnFromGalleryIntent.putExtra("picturePath",picturePath);
                            setResult(RESULT_OK,returnFromGalleryIntent);
                            finish();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }else{
                        Log.i(TAG, "RESULT_CANCELED");
                        Intent returnFromGalleryIntent = new Intent();
                        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnFromGalleryIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

MainActivity :

```
            package com.example.user.myapplication;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
            import android.content.Intent;
            import android.graphics.Bitmap;
            import android.graphics.Canvas;
            import android.graphics.Paint;
            import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
            import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
            import android.graphics.Rect;
            import android.net.Uri;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.os.Environment;
            import android.provider.MediaStore;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import android.view.MenuItem;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.ImageView;
            import android.widget.Toast;

            import java.io.File;
            import java.io.FileOutputStream;
            import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
            import java.util.Date;

            public class MainActivity extends Activity {

                private final static int GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE = 100;
                public static final int RESULT_CROP = 1;

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                    // onImage can be called with anything doesn't matter :
                    onImage(null);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                    int id = item.getItemId();

                    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
                    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
                }

                public void onImage(View view){
                    //Přechod do třídy GalleryUtil
                    Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GalleryUtil.class);
                    startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
                }

                //Vyhodnocení zadaných údajů
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    if (requestCode == GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
                        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                            String picturePath = data.getStringExtra("picturePath");
                            performCrop(picturePath);
                        }
                    }

                    if (requestCode == RESULT_CROP ) {
                        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

                            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                            Bitmap selectedBitmap = extras.getParcelable("data");
                            Bitmap croppedBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(selectedBitmap);

                            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);
                            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

                            String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                            FileOutputStream fOut = null;
                            String fileName = "Cropped_Image.jpg";

                            try {
                                // Not sure if the / is on the path or not
                                File file = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName); // the File to save to
                                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                                Bitmap pictureBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(selectedBitmap); // Using the cropped bitmap.
                                pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate

                                fOut.flush();
                                fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream
                                MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(), file.getName());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

                private void performCrop(String picUri) {
                    try {


                        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                        // indicate image type and Uri
                        File f = new File(picUri);
                        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

                        cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
                        // set crop properties
                        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                        // indicate aspect of desired crop
                        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                        // indicate output X and Y
                        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 280);
                        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 280);

                        // retrieve data on return
                        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
                        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP);
                    }
                    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
                    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                        // display an error message
                        String errorMessage = "your device doesn't support the crop action!";
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
                    }
                }

                public Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

                    final int color = 0xff424242;
                    final Paint paint = new Paint();
                    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    paint.setColor(color);
                    canvas.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                            bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
                    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);


                    return output;
                }
            }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                package="com.example.user.myapplication">

                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

                <application
                    android:allowBackup="true"
                    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:supportsRtl="true"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                    <activity
                        android:name=".MainActivity"
                        android:label="@string/app_name"
                        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
                    <activity android:name=".GalleryUtil"></activity>
                </application>

            </manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                tools:context="com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

The above code is working absolutely fine. I am able to get pics cropped and saved in my sd card.
Compare and check where you are doing wrong.

***To read every time app opens, we need to add following to main activity*** :

```
.
.
.
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Adding code for reading if file is already saved :
    loadImageFromStorage(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Cropped_Image.jpg")

        // onImage can be called with anything doesn't matter :
        onImage(null);
}

private void loadImageFromStorage(String path)
{

    try {
        File f=new File(path);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        img.setImageBitmap(b);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

...
```

Comment: Hi at last 3 lines I had to add try/catch and it cant resolve getImageBitmap and I put it below 
`imageView.setImageBitmap(getCroppedBitmap(selectedBitmap));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`
I dont know how to use it sorry. Can you help me more ?

Comment: According to my understanding of your code logic, you have correctly placed lines and added try/catch, and regarding getImageBitmap, Its a mistake in my given code... there is not default getImageBitmap function, it was used by me in my code... I have corrected and updated my above comment. Hope now it helps !

Comment: Before I will try it I want to ask you if I have placed it on correct place in my code (below `imageView.setImageBitmap(getCroppedBitmap(selectedBitmap)); imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);`)
in onActivityResult method. Thanks for reply

Comment: It is throwing error like 

 `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.tomiktuts.tom.mygirlfriendapp, PID: 16830
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=400, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.tomiktuts.tom.mygirlfriendapp/com.tomiktuts.tom.mygirlfriendapp.DashBoardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: At this code `pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more where are you getting this error, the exception says some variable went to null.

Comment: I seems obvious that pictureBitmap is null... plz confirm and investigate more....try to back track what reason made this variable null..... its something to do with getCroppedBitmap function. Are you calling the function twice ?? I mean once in setImageBitmap and once again below in new added line ??

Comment: I update my code upper on StackOverflow.
I use getCropped method only on setImageBitmap and in your code few lines below setImageBitmap (you can see upper)

Comment: Where are these lines :                                                                                                              if (requestCode == GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String picturePath = data.getStringExtra("picturePath");
            performCrop(picturePath);
        }
    }

Comment: Oh sorry bad edit. Now it is edited correctly I think :)

Comment: Yes still... problem is on this line `pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); `
When I crop the image and than save it... app shows dilog like saving... but it shows 500 miliseconds and than it fall down

Comment: I think this is mistake in file path then. I have updated a more generalize version .... it should be able to save now. Try again and let me know.

Comment: It still throw the same error. I can't use path `String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);` which is in galleryUtil ?

Comment: The one used in galleryUtil reads from database. Cursor is used in database to fetch column entry. You can't use same in here. Again double check do you have sd card in emulator/phone you are testing in?,  do you have permissions to write in SD card ? Because I don't see any other reason for such exception......otherwise I have to implement on my own and paste that code here.

Comment: How can I contact you please ? my email is tomas.viteck@gmail.com
I want to consult with you in future.

And yes I have sdCard in my test mobile

Comment: I am really sorry but it is uncomfortable for me to share contact info right now. But you can directly ask questions on android. This is a wonderful website for helping all android developers. I and many others will be available to help.

Comment: Let me try your code in my workspace... and will comment after root causing the issue.

Comment: Ok its no problem. Sorry I don't underestand your last comment

Comment: I meant I will try your code in my android studio, creating a new project and if I get the same exception will find what is causing this exception and will solve the problem and will comment then...just give me some time.

Comment: Ok so you don't need nothing from me now ?

Comment: Will let you know soon

Comment: I am pasting the code which is working absolutely perfectly on my testing device (onePlus one - android 6.0). Plz see the updated code above.

Comment: So my code is correct but I test it on bad device ?

Comment: Compare code with mine and then decide .... there is no device specification required for this type of code ... its very simple code ..... so it will work on any device having sd card working fine. If you can save files on your sd card, then its your code the problem, never device.

Comment: Ohhh yes now it is okay. Thank you. I have few questions.

1. How can I read saved picture and load it on every app start
2. what if user havent SD card ?

Comment: Answer to first is simple, we write to SD card using FileOutputStream, now to read we can use FileInputStream.

Comment: For second answer, we can write to internal memory of device, but very carefully as memory leaks there can cause some serious issues.

Comment: Thank you for explanation but I never before work with this saving I always save everything into  shared prefs. So can you show me code which I can use on start of activity ? :)

Comment: You dont need to use shared preferences for this....since you have only one imageView in your xml file. Just do it as I have updated in the code above, to read from sd card and update the cropped image. I have not tested but I assume it will work.

Comment: I will leave now.... its too late at night here (4 am). Keep on learning... and asking people all your doubts. I was also once as curious as you are. Appreciate your efforts ... and keep on doing same ... you will be a great developer in future to come, if you keep on the same track. All the best... :)

Comment: Thank youu very muchh Im soo happy .. thank you for your time ! I want to be your friend :) I do great grafics so I can help you too . :) so thank you very much. I have last one big problem If do you will have time and if you want please help me :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34027530/how-to-remove-sharedpreferences-from-array. And last time THANK YOU MASTER !